# Run android application and game from google play on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks

Is there already made solution to run android application/game on emulator for example using Eclipse or other soft? I need to see how one program works right now, but my android device is in the service center now.

I found this BlueStacks but I am not sure that I can trust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Genymotion

http://www.genymotion.com/features/

Best emulator out there and support Google Play

There are also some Android virtual machine, but Genymotion is by far the best one

[image]

Comment: ok I am instilling it right now. The link for download is only available if you are the member of site.

Comment: Yep, that's because you download virtual machines from their server, I guess

Comment: the proble is how I can use Google Play because I can find it on emulator. But emulator really prefect!

Comment: You have different virtual machines to download, somes contain Google Play, look at their description! You even have Android 4.3 ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks, just need to make sure that the virtual device name mentions "Google Apps"

Answer (score 0):

You can also emulate android devices in a virtual machine (or on your hardware) using the iso image provided by http://www.android-x86.org/

So you make your PC to an Android device, including the Play store...

There is a fresh Andoird 4.3 image you can use, for example with VirtualBox.